# Facebook share on behalf of another site

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, share, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to have a share button on my site that can share on behalf of YouTube.  Let's say the page is http://www.mysite.com/test.html.

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com">
        <meta property="og:description" content="My custom YouTube share">
        <meta property="og:title" content="YouTube Share">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/preview.png">
    </head>
<body>

    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com%2Ftest.html">Share</a

</body>
<html>
```

But it's completely ignoring my meta properties when I click the Share.  How can I get it so that Facebook looks at all of my declared meta properties?  Or is it impossible to share on behalf of another site?

EDIT:
Here's a sample screenshot of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: try it with changing the u parameter of the a href to your urlized youtube url `<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com">Share</a>`

Comment: The metadata is taken from the final URL after-redirect, so don't redirect Facebook's crawler using the og:url tag

Comment: @Mik, the point of my question is whether or not the external URL I share can have the attributes that I specify (description, title, image).

Comment: @Igy I see.  So what do you suggest I do to achieve what I want?

Comment: I've updated the question with a sample screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve.  I hope that helps explain the desired functionality :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get custom text on another site's content share, you could use a URL on your site as the og:url, serve facebook's crawler the meta tags with the title, description etc that you want, but redirect other browsers to YouTube

(i.e share a link to a URL on your site, then on that URL have logic which says

if user agent == Facebook's crawler serve meta tags, else HTTP 301 redirect to youtube

Comment: Interesting approach. While it doesn't satisfy all of the requirements I had, it does satisfy most.  Thanks Igy!